# Can't log in to root in Winscp (access denied)

Tags: raspbian, ssh

[image]

I'm using WINSCP to transfer files to my pi but I cannot send anything if I'm not logged in as root...

How to log in as root ?

Comment: Confirm that you actually created a root password and that it works in some other context, and edit in the contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: could you please explain
i opened ssh_config but didn't know what to edit
i'm still new to all this

Comment: There's `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`.  Cut and paste the contents of **the latter** into your question.

Comment: You should not be logging in as root for security reasons. Instead login as the Pi user and copy the files to a location where the Pi user has access (like /home/pi/Downloads, then login over SSH or directly using a keyboard and mouse as the Pi user. finally by using either su or sudo move the files to their final destination.

Comment: thx for your help 
i found something on the net but it didnt work
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes   // i changed it to yes it was no password 
StrictModes yes 

thx for ur help u and steve..

Comment: problem solved 
solution is here : 
http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/06/how-to-setup-a-web-server-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Hello and welcome. If you like, write up a short summary of the solution as your own answer here.